# How can I make a floated link element 100% height of its parent div

Tags: html, css, height, match

I have a navigation at the bottom of a page. Everything works fine and how I want it to except for one small bug and I can't seem to work out a solution...

When the page name is long and you view it on an iPad size screen, the name goes onto two lines - which is fine - how ever I would like the adjacent button to match the height (so they both stay the same height) and to both stay horizontally aligned to the centre.

Ive tried a few different things like display table and table cell, flex etc. but I can't seem to work out a solution that works properly.

Any suggestions on how I can do this...?

```css
.footerNav-wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #000;
 padding: 35px 0;
 z-index: 9000;
 position: relative;
}

.footerNav {
 width: 90%;
 max-width: 1000px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.navArrow-left {
 float: left;
 margin: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 30%;
 left: 10px
}

.navArrow-right {
 float: right;
 margin: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 30%;
 right: 10px;
}

.footerNav a {
 width: 49%;
 font-family: 'ABCSans-Regular', Arial, sans-serif;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 background-color: #000;
 color:#ffc600;
 margin: 0;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 18px;
 letter-spacing: 0px;
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
 text-decoration: none;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 position: relative;
}

.footerNav a:hover {
 border: 1px solid #ffc600;
 background-color: #ffc600;
 color: #000;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.left {
 float: left;
 text-align: left !important;
 padding: 15px 15px 12px 45px;
}

.right {
 float: right;
 text-align: right !important;
 padding: 15px 45px 12px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="footerNav-wrapper">
 <nav class="footerNav">
     <a href="#" class="left">
         <img src="images/arrow-left-white.png"  class="navArrow-left" alt="Previous page">
         PREVIOUS PAGE NAME
        </a>
        <a href="c#" class="right">
            NEXT PAGE NAME - THIS IS AN EXTRA LONG NAME
            <img src="images/arrow-right-white.png"  class="navArrow-right" alt="Next page">
        </a>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;` to do that if you need to support really old browsers (http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). However i would recomment using flexbox as [GvM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40477470/6357653) pointed out.

There is an interesting article about serveral ways to do what you want to do: https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

```css
.footerNav-wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #000;
 padding: 35px 0;
 z-index: 9000;
 position: relative;
}

.footerNav {
    display: table;
 width: 90%;
 max-width: 1000px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.navArrow-left {
 float: left;
 margin: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 30%;
 left: 10px
}

.navArrow-right {
 float: right;
 margin: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 30%;
 right: 10px;
}

.footerNav a {
 width: 49%;
 font-family: 'ABCSans-Regular', Arial, sans-serif;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 background-color: #000;
 color:#ffc600;
 margin: 0;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 18px;
 letter-spacing: 0px;
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
 text-decoration: none;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 position: relative;
}

.footerNav a:hover {
 border: 1px solid #ffc600;
 background-color: #ffc600;
 color: #000;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.left {
    display: table-cell;
 text-align: left !important;
 padding: 15px 15px 12px 45px;
}

.right {
    display: table-cell;
 text-align: right !important;
 padding: 15px 45px 12px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="footerNav-wrapper">
 <nav class="footerNav">
     <a href="#" class="left">
         <img src="images/arrow-left-white.png"  class="navArrow-left" alt="Previous page">
         PREVIOUS PAGE NAME
        </a>
        <div style="display: table-cell; width: 2%;"></div>
        <a href="c#" class="right">
            NEXT PAGE NAME - THIS IS AN EXTRA LONG NAME
            <img src="images/arrow-right-white.png"  class="navArrow-right" alt="Next page">
        </a>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

i used `display:flex;` on `.footerNav` and added margin to classes left and right.

```css
.footerNav-wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #000;
 padding: 35px 0;
 z-index: 9000;
 position: relative;
}

.footerNav {
 width: 90%;
 max-width: 1000px;
 margin: 0 auto;
    display:flex;
}

.navArrow-left {
 float: left;
 margin: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 30%;
 left: 10px
}

.navArrow-right {
 float: right;
 margin: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 30%;
 right: 10px;
}

.footerNav a {
 width: 49%;
 font-family: 'ABCSans-Regular', Arial, sans-serif;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 background-color: #000;
 color:#ffc600;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 18px;
 letter-spacing: 0px;
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
 text-decoration: none;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 position: relative;
}

.footerNav a:hover {
 border: 1px solid #ffc600;
 background-color: #ffc600;
 color: #000;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.left {
 float: left;
 text-align: left !important;
 padding: 15px 15px 12px 45px;
    margin-right: 1%;
}

.right {
 float: right;
 text-align: right !important;
 padding: 15px 45px 12px 15px;
    margin-left: 1%;
}
```

```html
<div class="footerNav-wrapper">
 <nav class="footerNav">
     <a href="#" class="left">
         <img src="images/arrow-left-white.png"  class="navArrow-left" alt="Previous page">
         PREVIOUS PAGE NAME
        </a>
        <a href="c#" class="right">
            NEXT PAGE NAME - THIS IS AN EXTRA LONG NAME
            <img src="images/arrow-right-white.png"  class="navArrow-right" alt="Next page">
        </a>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </nav>
</div>
```